# AngularJS - Ioinc Framework write $http request like in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I need to create authentification for server. The authentifcation is going over NTLM method on Windows Server. The basic is I know how to setup the AJAX call in jQuery, and wehen I call that url everthing go fine. I get response 200 and thai si ok. On the other side in Ionic Framework with AngularJS i have some issue. When I setup my $http request to server the reponse is alert window with dialog where I need to eneter **username** and **password**.

My question is:
I'm I doing something wrong in Angular Ionic Framework or Ionic Framewrok with AngularJS cannot make such request.

Below is my sample code:

## jquery - code

```
$('#heloo').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            async: true,
            dataType: "json",
            username: 'test',
            password: 'test',
            xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown);
            },
            success: function(xml) {
                console.log(xml);
            }
        });
    })
```

This code give me status 200 after request to url and everthing is ok with request.

## ionic framework - angularjs

```
$http({

          url : url,
          method : 'GET',
          async : true,
          cache : false,
          headers: {
            'Content-type': 'json',
            "Accept" : "application/json"
          },
          responseType:'json',
          username: 'test',
          password: 'test',
          xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
          }
        }).success(function(data){
          alert("login Successfully");
        }).error(function(error){
          alert("login error");
        });
```

After calling this service in angular problem is dialog where I must eneter username and password. I dont know where is catch.

Comment: I can provide full url for test purpose.

Comment: The problem is probably with the config you are using with $http; async, responseType, username, password, xhrFields are not valid parameters. Take a look at the [reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)